# How to redirect blog pages with regex redirects?

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301

I would like to redirect all of my blog pages to a new URL.

**For example:** 
I would like to redirect: 
http://adaras.se/blogg/page/35

... to:
http://adaras.se/blog/page/35

I am using Redirects Yoast SEO and don't get how to use regex redirects. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blogg/.*
RewriteRule blogg/(.*)?$ blog/$1 [L]
```

[EDIT] to add link to online tester.

Yuu can see this rule working for your example here:
[image: http://htaccess.mwl.be/]

and try it yourself on the online .htaccess tester at this URL: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

If it does not work on your Yoast plugin, check the generated .htaccess file and you can also try to match everything to redirect to Google for instance to see if your htaccess is really taken in consideration! :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried to paste this code in the plugin settings for regex redirects and I also tried it in my .htaccess file. But it didn't work. 

Any other ideas?

Comment: Also when you tried on your .htaccess file, did you make sure that your hosting server or localhost has the rewrite engine on? You want to make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled in configs and try to add `RewriteEngine on` to the top of your file if not present!